Synchronisation of pushing and presenting view controllers
My app has a scenario where one module shows a view controller, and a second module tries to push another. Those modules are separated pieces of software (a framework and the app).
The problem is if there is a presentation in progress (animation), pushing the second view controller fails silently.
For the sake of simplification, here is the code which helps to understand the issue:
class RedViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        presentAndPush()
    }
    
    private func presentAndPush() {
        //called from the first module
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "World", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
        
        //called from the second module bit later
        assert(self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count == 1)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(YellowViewController(), animated: true)
        assert(self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count == 1) //Note! viewControllers.count remains equal to 1
    }
}

class YellowViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}

The YellowViewController is never shown.

How can I synchronise presenting and pushing view controllers using UIKit only? I can not use custom flags, timestamps, etc., in the application and have knowledge about them in the framework code.

Are you expecting the "yellow" VC to slide-in (get pushed) while the Alert Controller is showing?

@DonMag, Not completely. I want to be able to know in the framework that the application is showing an alert. Thanks to this, I will be able to, for example, delay pushing another view controller. I need to create synchronisation mechanism which allows to successful use of pushViewController in the framework. while is not crucial, it can be sequential. What comes to my mind for the time being is to compare array of added view controllers before and after of pushViewController. If arrays are equal, wait for a moment and then retry. I do not like this solution though.

Without understanding anything about your framework / application relationship, it sounds like your only option would be delay / check / delay / check / etc...

One approach:
func doThePush() {
    guard let n: Int = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count else { return }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(YellowViewController(), animated: true)
    if self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count == n {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
            self.doThePush()
        })
    }
}

